# Knockout bootstrap modal issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I try to write by my own a Knockout application in which are available nested arrays.
I'm trying to create a Bootstrap modal window which will help me to add a new item of embedded List.
I create the everything but unfortunately the new item is always added to the last array.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

What I wrote for now is available on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63tGP/1/)
JS

```
ko.bindingHandlers.showModal = {
         init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
             $(element).modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: true, show: false });
         },
         update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
 
             var value = valueAccessor();
             if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value)) {
                  $(element).modal('show');
                 $("input", element).focus();
             }
             else {
 
                 $(element).modal('hide');
             }
         }
     };
 
 
function Task(data) {
   this.family = ko.observable(data.family); }
 
var personModel = function() {  self = this;    self.people =
ko.observableArray([
       new testModel("Person",["one","two","three"]),
       new testModel("Person2",["one2","two2","three2"]),
       new testModel("Person3",["one3","two3","three3"])
]); }
 
function TaskItem(data) {
     this.family = ko.observable(data); 
}
 
var testModel = function(name,children){
 
   self = this;
   self.itemToAdd = ko.observable("");
   self.name = name;
   self.items = ko.observableArray([]);

   for(var i = 0; i<children.length;i++){
      self.items.push(new TaskItem(children[i]));
   }
 
   self.currentItem = ko.observable();
   self.newTaskText = ko.observable();
   self.displaySubmitModal = ko.observable(false);
   self.showModal = function(){
       self.displaySubmitModal(true);
   };
   self.closeSubmitModal = function(){
       self.displaySubmitModal(false);
       self.newTaskText("");
   };
 
   // Operations
   self.addTask = function() {
       self.items.push(new Task({ family: this.newTaskText() }));
       self.newTaskText("");
       self.displaySubmitModal(false);
   }; 
}
 
ko.applyBindings(new personModel());
```

and HTML

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: people">
        <li>
            <div>
                <span data-bind="text: name">has <span data-bind='text: items().length'>&nbsp;</span>
                    children: </span>
                <ul data-bind="foreach: items">
                    <li><span href="#" data-bind="text: family"></span></li>
                </ul>



                <a href="#" data-bind="click: showModal">Add new Item</a>
                <div id="modalNew" class="modal hide fade" data-bind="showModal:displaySubmitModal()">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-bind="click: closeSubmitModal" data-dismiss="modal"
                            aria-hidden="true">
                            &times;</button>
                        <h3>
                            My Editor</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        Add task:
                        <input data-bind="value: newTaskText" placeholder="What needs to be done?" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: addTask">Add Note</a> <a href="#"
                            class="btn" data-bind="click: closeSubmitModal" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

---

### EDIT

After many many tries it doesn`t work. I don`t have Idea what I`m doing wrong and how to fix it.
What I observe is that "Add new Item" always i loading the last Modal window for the(Person 3). Even If I remove the rest Modals and left only the first one the new item is adding for the third person.

That's why I`m asking:

Is it possible to create nested array which will have a "Add new Item" button which will open a Modal window(twitter-bootstrap) with all field for the new item and will add this item to the selected array?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show twitter bootstrap modal dialog automatically with knockout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14683953/show-twitter-bootstrap-modal-dialog-automatically-with-knockout)

Comment: "possible duplicate" is not duplicate. There are two different issues. Like I wrote I already have a Modal view but always is adding new items to the last Array

Comment: I'm wondering if the problem is because you've got the modal defined inside the foreach:people loop.  That means you're generating HTML for three modals all with the same id.  Not sure how jQuery will handle showing a modal that appears 3 times in the document.  Perhaps it's always showing the last one which could explain why you're always seeing the last one shown.

Comment: I was wondering the same. After that I made the first one only visible but the item is again adding to the last array. I`m almost sure that that`s why I have problem with this but the question is how to create a only one modal which will be load for all arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is nearly working.

But there is one javascript issue, a global variable pollution, which prevents it from working.

fixed your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/63tGP/3/

it fixed

```
self = this;
```

to

```
var self = this;
```

`self = this;` is same as `window.self = this;`

the result is, at the end, the self in your addTask() always points to the last testModel.

Comment: Thank you @huocp :) I already fixed it but i didn`t have time to add answer. I will check your post like answer and I will add a my solution. Regards

Comment: Good finding! `"use strict";` would have helped here.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes ago I already find a solution.

I wrote of my problem on googlegroups and one guy updated my jsFiddle.

He add a revealing module pattern.

If somebody is interest of our discussion [here is a link to it](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/knockoutjs/MNdkZc0XEYM)

And my update [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZdZ62/2/)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.showModal = {
         init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
             $(element).modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: true, show: false });
         },
         update: function (element, valueAccessor) {

             var value = valueAccessor();
             if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor())) {
                  $(element).modal('show');
                 $("input", element).focus();
             }
             else {

                 $(element).modal('hide');
             }
         }
     };


var Task = function(data) {
   var family = ko.observable(data.family);
    return { family: family};
}

var personModel = function() {  
    var people = ko.observableArray([
       new testModel("Person",["one","two","three"]),
       new testModel("Person2",["one2","two2","three2"]),
       new testModel("Person3",["one3","two3","three3"])
       ]);
    return {
             people: people
            };
};

var TaskItem = function(data) {
     var family = ko.observable(data); 
    return { family: family};
}

var testModel = function(familyName,children){
   var itemToAdd = ko.observable("");
   var name = familyName;
   var items = ko.observableArray([]);

   for(var i = 0; i<children.length;i++){
      items.push(new TaskItem(children[i]));
   }

   var currentItem = ko.observable();
   var newTaskText = ko.observable();
   var displaySubmitModal = ko.observable(false);
   var showModal = function(){
       displaySubmitModal(true);
   };
   var closeSubmitModal = function(){
       displaySubmitModal(false);
       newTaskText("");
   };

   // Operations
   var addTask = function() {
       items.push(new Task({ family: newTaskText() }));
       newTaskText("");
       displaySubmitModal(false);
   }; 

    return {
        items: items,
        showModal: showModal,
        displaySubmitModal: displaySubmitModal,
        closeSubmitModal: closeSubmitModal,
        name: name,
        newTaskText: newTaskText,
        addTask: addTask,

    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new personModel());
```

Regards